# Determine type of class to add attributes into treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, datatemplate

I have a class which is something like this:

```
public class PLOAMD_STRUCT
    {
        public ushort ONU_ID { get; set; }                   
        public byte MessageType { get; private set; }               
        public byte SequenceNumber { get; set; }            
        public PLOAM_Messages.MESSAGE MessageContent { get; private set; }      
        public ulong MIC { get; set; }
    }
```

MessageContent belongs to abstract class:

```
public abstract class MESSAGE
    {

    }
```

And the content can be one of many classes which extends it like:

```
public class PROFILE_MESSAGE : MESSAGE
    {
        public byte Version { get; set; }
        public byte Profile { get; set; }
        public bool FEC { get; set; }
        public byte Delimiter { get; set; }
        public byte Preamble_Length { get; set; }
        public ulong Preamble { get; set; }
        public ulong PON_Tag { get; set; }
    }

public class SERIAL_NUMBER_GRANT_MESSAGE : MESSAGE
    {
        public uint Vendor_ID { get; set; }
        public uint Vendor_SSN { get; set; }
        public uint Random_Delay { get; set; }
    }
```

In XAML I need to determine a type of class and depending on type show its attributes. I have this:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="PLOAMd[]" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Payload.Header.PLOAMd}">
                                        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition />
                                                        <RowDefinition />
                                                        <RowDefinition />
                                                        <RowDefinition />
                                                        <RowDefinition />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="ONU ID" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ONU_ID}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Message type" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MessageType}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Sequence number" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SequenceNumber}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
                                                        <TreeViewItem Header="Message content" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                                                            <TreeViewItem.Items>
                                                                <!-- Content HERE! -->
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MessageContent.Version}" />
                                                            </TreeViewItem.Items>
                                                        </TreeViewItem>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="MIC" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MIC}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" />
                                                </Grid>
                                                </Border>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>

                                    </TreeViewItem>
```

If I use code under comment:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MessageContent.Version}" />
```

and the type of message is PROFILE_MESSAGE it seems it retype it automatically and gives me right value. But how to do it that it will choose right structure and shows it. So if the message will be type of SERIAL_NUMBER_GRANT_MESSAGE I will only see:

```
Vendor_ID
Vendor_SSN
Random_Delay
```

and etc. Constructing of blocks is easy I only need to choose one of maybe templates and show it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to use a DataTemplateSelector: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried it but nothing happen. It seems that problem is that message content is not collection so i cant put it as ItemsSource for TreeViewItem. Or maybe Im doing something wrong. Can you provide me some code how to do it ?